# I am not able to find how can I achieve the test coverage for the nested classes please help me with the code below:

Tags: apex, unit-test

### Here is the class :

```
public class Out 
{

    public Meta meta;
    public Response response;

    public class In1
    {
        public List<String> COMPANY;
        public List<String> SUCCESSFUL;
        public List<String> FUNDS;
        public List<String> FAILED;
    }

    public class IN2 
    {
        public Boolean successful;
        public String id;
        public In1 In1;
        public Integer number_of_resources_sent;
        public String access_token;
        public String uuid;
    }

    public class IN3 
    {
        public List<IN4> errors;
        public Integer status_code;
        public Integer version;
        public Double execution_time;
        public Integer timestamp;
    }

    public class IN4 
    {
        public String message;
        public String code;
    }

    public static Response parse(String json) 
    {
        return (Response) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Response.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Help It's urgent....

Comment: You should be fine with just instantiating your classes with empty/dummy values + executing your parse function with expected input and checking whether the result is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Generalised Code for test class can be written as below,

```
//Create instance of inner class as 

OuterCls.InnerCls1 innerCls1 = new OuterCls.InnerCls1();

//Access all the fields in inner class in any way, one way is
innerCls1.innerClsField1= <some value>;
```

All the classes will be covered.

Answer (score 0):

Put getters and setters for your class variables.

```
public class Out 
{
    public Meta meta{get; set;}
    public Response response{get; set;}

    public class In1
    {
        public List<String> COMPANY{get; set;}
        public List<String> SUCCESSFUL{get; set;}
        public List<String> FUNDS{get; set;}
        public List<String> FAILED{get; set;}
    }

    //  Do the same for rest of the classes as well
}
```

Then instantiate them in your test class as usual

```
Out.In1 oin = new Out.In1();
oin.COMPANY = new List<String>();
....
```